# In office-js, how to download a single sheet as excel file？

Tags: excel, ms-office, office365, office-js, excel-addins

I would like to download or display a separate sheet as excel or pdf file to my users to see, but I can not find a similar api, I'm not sure if there is such a function.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean?  Are you trying to import in an excel file, or export to a separate file / PDF, or ....?

Comment: Yes, I want to export a separate excel file, or a separate pdf file